# Set azure blob in open edx MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL

Tags: django, azure, openedx

I have installed open edx in two different machines, and access by the load balancer.
I have configured the Scorm xblock https://github.com/raccoongang/edx_xblock_scorm in open edx.
I want to upload scorm in azure blob so both machine access.

My configuration in lms.env.json and cms.env.json

```
"AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME": "myedx",
"AZURE_CONTAINER": "edx",
"DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE": "openedx.core.storage.AzureStorageMedia",
"MEDIA_ROOT": "https://myedx.blob.core.windows.net/edx/",
"MEDIA_URL": "https://myedx.blob.core.windows.net/edx/",
```

My sotorage class

```
class AzureStorageMedia(AzureStorage):
    account_name = settings.AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
    account_key = settings.AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY
    azure_container = settings.AZURE_CONTAINER
    expiration_secs = None
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

My error

```
    resp = descriptor.handle(handler, req, suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xblock/mixins.py", line 89, in handle
    return self.runtime.handle(self, handler_name, request, suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/x_module.py", line 1347, in handle
    return super(MetricsMixin, self).handle(block, handler_name, request, suffix=suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xblock/runtime.py", line 1037, in handle
    results = handler(request, suffix)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx_xblock_scorm/scormxblock/scormxblock.py", line 164, in studio_submit
    os.mkdir(SCORM_ROOT)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://myedx.blob.core.windows.net/edx/scorm'
```

How to solve this error.

Comment: please add your `scormxblock.py` file code

Comment: Hi Meha, my ```scormxblock.py``` same as this https://github.com/raccoongang/edx_xblock_scorm/blob/master/scormxblock/scormxblock.py, I have not added any extra code.

Comment: okay, what you have set `MEDIA_ROOT` in `settings.py` file?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT =  'https://myedx.blob.core.windows.net/edx/'

Comment: Then in your azure container do you have edx folder?

Comment: Yes, the azure container has edx folder.

Comment: `os.mkdir` will create a directory in local machine, that's why the error is coming, for azure you do not need to check explicitly, try removing this code `# Check whether SCORM_ROOT exists
            if not os.path.exists(SCORM_ROOT):
                os.mkdir(SCORM_ROOT)`.

Comment: `SCORM_ROOT = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'scorm')` this will create 'scrom' in azure. @RahulRai

Comment: can you add stack trace of diffract error

Comment: Getting diffract error ` File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx_xblock_scorm/scormxblock/scormxblock.py", line 176, in studio_submit temporary_zip = open(temporary_path, 'wb') IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'myedx.blob.core.windows.net/edx/scorm/my.zip`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209504/discussion-between-meha-parekh-and-rahul-rai).